# SQL: Group by Histogram Error: 'select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause'

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I'm new to SQL language and I'm getting a 'select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause' error with my sample code below.

Here, I have a table 'pkg_data' with a pkg_type column (color catergory), and pkg_weight, I'd like to use case statements to categorize the packages by their weight and count the packages per bin.

The code below works without the group by statement. I'd like to also have a sub category per pkg_type. Without the grouping, I will get a single histogram table with all pkg_type counts combined but I want to have multiple histogram rows per pkg_type.

```
with pkg_size as 
 (
 select 
 pkg_type,
 date,
 pkg_weight,

 case
  when pkg_weight >= 0.5 AND pkg_weight < 0.5 then 'small'
  when pkg_weight >= 1 AND pkg_weight < 2 then 'medium'
  when pkg_weight >= 2 AND pkg_weight < 3 then 'large'
  else 'out of range'
 end as pkg_size_histo

 from pkg_data
 where date > x1 and date <= y
 and pkg_size_hist is not null

 --group by pkg_type -- error: select clause is neither an aggregate nor in 
 the group by clause
 order by date

)
select pkg_size_hist, count(pkg_size_hist )
from pkg_size
group by pkg_size_hist ;
```

---

current output:
[image]

expected output:
[image]

Please help. Thanks.

---

Update:

I think this quick fix works. Better programming tips with this example are very welcomed. Thanks.

```
select pkg_type,pkg_size_hist, count(pkg_size_hist )
from pkg_size

group by pkg_type, pkg_size_hist ;
```

Comment: If you want to group by `pkg_type`, what do you want to do with the columns date, pkg_weight, pkg_size_histo? There can be multiple values per each `pkg_type`. You'll need to pick the `MAX()` or the `MIN()` or the average, etc. of those columns.

Comment: @TheImpaler, in this example the order by date is unnecessary. I just need to pkg count per weight category and per type but I think I figured it now.

Comment: select pkg_type,pkg_size_hist, count(pkg_size_hist )
from pkg_size
group by pkg_type, pkg_size_hist ;